# Can I set the affinity of a multi-processed Nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, affinity

Background:

---

I have a multi-processed NodeJS app, that does some heavy CPU processing. The app uses the `child_process` module, to fork additional subprocesses.

The logic is:

main loop -> fork a Master Worker -> The MasterWorker forks up to **N** workers -> N workers do processing -> MasterWorker collects results -> posts back to main loop.

**N** here is always large enough, and greater than the number of CPU cores. Let's say that N=100, # of cores=20, and that a single worker uses 20-25% of a core. This results in 100% CPU usage for a very long time.

Obviously, I can just set **N**=# of Cores-1, but this limits my throughput.

Setting it to (5*(# of Cores)) -1 is still not perfect, as it depends on what other stuff the machine is doing.

---

My question:

**I would like to keep 1 core totally "free", in order to not bring the machine to its knees while this app runs.**

**Is there another way that doesn't involve changing the number of worker processes?**

I am aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522859/1543677, but it's not really doable for the subprocesses the app spawns.

Comment: `child_process` creates _processes_, **not** threads.

Comment: @AKX thanks, updated with correct terminology.

Comment: So why couldn't the workers call `taskset` on their own PIDs when they start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple after all (thanks @AKX).

1. Install [nodeaffinity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeaffinity)
2. At the top of each worker, use:

---

```
var nc = require('nodeaffinity');
nc.setAffinity(262143);    //Cores #0-#17, modify to your liking
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want an approximate round-robin between eg. 5 cores, you could use `setAffinity(1 << (process.pid % 5));`